# Physique and exports from 3ds Max

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, file-format, skeletal-animation, export

Are there any file formats that support Physique and are compatible with Unity? I really don't want to start over from scratch and have to use the Skin modifier...

Comment: Yes there are - FBX supports that. You need to get a Physique to skin conversion 3ds Max plugin. Not sure if it is still supported by the newest Max

Comment: Great, thanks! :). Could you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are - FBX supports that. You need to get a Physique to skin conversion 3ds Max plugin. Not sure if it is still supported by the newest Max.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any that work with Max 2014 - could you link one, if possible?

Comment: That is what I said, "Not sure if it is still supported by the newest Max." which by far, is no. 2014. You will need an older version. I have to work with Max 2013, because 2014 is not supported by my engine :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I should have a 2011 version lying around somewhere.